# Xamarin.Forms Implementing OneSignal Android NotificationExtenderService

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I want to implement the NotificationExtenderService shown in the answer to this question: [OneSignal - ANDROID - NotificationExtenderService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56580587/onesignal-android-notificationextenderservice)

However, this implementation uses native java code.  I need to implement this same solution in my Xamarin.Forms C# Android project.  The OneSignal documentation only gives the exact same native code example shown in the answer to the question above.  I cannot find any examples of how to implement it in the Xamarin C# project.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no other way. To set up a [notification extender service](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#section-notification-extender-service) you must write native code.